# How to set the marker on google map using ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I need to set the markers dynamically in google map using the ajax call.
How it possible

I need the code code for that.

i want ajax call to update google map.

update the marker dynamically using ajax

```
  var locations = [['spain',-41.054502,160.136719,'Uk',35.666222 ,39.019184],['china',58.025555,87.714844,'United Stat',35.666222 ,-44.472656],['Hong Kong',62.057586,44.121094,'United Stat',12.801088,18.457031],['Hong Kong',40.4523,102.128906,'United Stat',35.666222 ,-70.472656],['Hong Kong',28.526622,-76.816406,'United Stat',35.666222 ,-65.472656],['Hong Kong',28.526622,-76.816406,'United Stat',35.666222 ,-40.472656],['Hong Kong',28.526622,-45.816406,'United Stat',35.666222 ,-44.472656],['Hong Kong',28.526622,-24.816406,'United Stat',35.666222 ,-44.472656],['Hong Kong',28.526622,-76.816406,'United Stat',35.666222 ,-44.472656],['Hong Kong',28.526622,-76.816406,'United Stat',35.666222 ,-44.472656]]; 
function initialize() { 
var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType( 
[ 
{ 
"featureType": "all", 
"elementType": "labels.text.fill", 
"stylers": [ 
{ 
"saturation": 36 
}, 
{ 
"color": "#ffffff" 
}, 
{ 
"lightness": 40 
} 
] 
}, 
{ 
"featureType": "all", 
"elementType": "labels.text.stroke", 
"stylers": [ 
{ 
"visibility": "on" 
}, 
{ 
"color": "#000000" 
}, 
{ 
"lightness": 16 
} 
] 
}, 
{ 
"featureType": "all", 
"elementType": "labels.icon", 
"stylers": [ 
{ 
"visibility": "off" 
} 
] 
}, 
{ 
"featureType": "administrative", 
"elementType": "geometry.fill", 
"stylers": [ 
{ 
"color": "#ffffff" 
}, 
{ 
"lightness": 20 
} 
] 
}, 
{ 
"featureType": "administrative", 
"elementType": "geometry.stroke", 
"stylers": [ 
{ 
"color": "#ffffff" 
}, 
{ 
"lightness": 17 
}, 
{ 
"weight": 1.2 
} 
] 
}, 
{ 
"featureType": "landscape", 
"elementType": "geometry", 
"stylers": [ 
{ 
"color": "#000000" 
}, 
{ 
"lightness": 20 
} 
] 
}, 
{ 
"featureType": "poi", 
"elementType": "geometry", 
"stylers": [ 
{ 
"color": "#ffffff" 
}, 
{ 
"lightness": 21 
} 
] 
}, 
{ 
"featureType": "road.highway", 
"elementType": "geometry.fill", 
"stylers": [ 
{ 
"color": "#000000" 
}, 
{ 
"lightness": 17 
} 
] 
}, 
{ 
"featureType": "road.highway", 
"elementType": "geometry.stroke", 
"stylers": [ 
{ 
"color": "#000000" 
}, 
{ 
"lightness": 29 
}, 
{ 
"weight": 0.2 
} 
] 
}, 
{ 
"featureType": "road.arterial", 
"elementType": "geometry", 
"stylers": [ 
{ 
"color": "#000000" 
}, 
{ 
"lightness": 18 
} 
] 
}, 
{ 
"featureType": "road.local",
```

i used this code for updating markers

Comment: this is not a code writing service. pls provide what you tried we can help troubleshoot it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like this. Since I do not know the ajax call you want to make I mocked it and I am calling the `fakeAjaxCall` function that returns a **lat-lng** object as shown on the example

```
//This is the fake ajax call we are supposed to call
var fakeAjaxCall = function(success, error) {
  var response = {lat: 59.327, lng: 18.067};
  window.setTimeout(success.bind(null, response), 1000);
}

//Our map object is already initialized, no marker is there yet.
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 13,
  center: {lat: 59.325, lng: 18.070}
});

//Here we make the ajax call. We expect a lat-lng response like the one from fake ajax call
fakeAjaxCall(function success(responseMarker){
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: responseMarker,
    map: map,
    title: 'Hello World!'
  });
})
```